# Почему не выводит ссылку?

Tags: php, html

```
<? if ($myrow['login'] == $login) {
//вывод данных
        echo '<div class="change"><a href='change.php?id=$_SESSION[id]'><span class="change">ред.</span></a> </div>';
        }
        else
        {
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А ты пробовал просто вот так `<a href='change.php?id=$_SESSION[id]</a>`

Просто ты php открываешь внутри php так нельзя

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if ($myrow['login'] == $login) 
   {
     //вывод данных
     echo "
     <div class="change">
     <a href='change.php?id= ".$_SESSION['id']." '><span class='change'>ред.       </span></a> 
     </div>";
   }
   else
   {
   }
?>
```

Вот так правильно!